# Difficulties installing JSON and extracting Development Kit in Ruby (Windows 8)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, windows

I am trying to install Ruby for Windows 8. I successfully installed Ruby and Rails, and was in the process of installing all the gems for rails. I ran into this error message, along the way.

```
Gem::InstallError: The 'json' native gem requires installed build tools.

Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit from 
http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads and follow the instructions at 
https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller An error occured while installing
json (1.8.1), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that 
'gem install json -v '1.8.1'' succeeds before bundling.
```

Following the instructions I then tried

```
gem install json -v '1.8.1'
```

Unfortunately I received the same error message.

I decided to go to the rubyinstaller.org website to download the development kit.

My Ruby Version is 2.0.0, so following the instructions, I decided it would be best to download this development kit.

```
DevKit-mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432-sfx.exe
```

From the website, there were three development kits available for download, one for Ruby Versions 1.87 and 1.93. There was also a development kit available for Ruby 2.0, but it was for 32bit versions only. Since my operating system is a 64bit operating system, I downloaded this development kit.

```
For use with Ruby 2.0 (x64 – 64bits only)
```

I also noticed that all of the files were 7 Zip Extractable Archives. I decided it would be best to extract to this directory.

```
C:\Ruby200
```

When I went into that directory, I noticed the following were added to it.

```
etc (directory)
  >fstab.sample
  >inputrc.default
  >profile
  >termcap
mingw (directory)
  >bin (directory)
  >contrib (directory)
  >include (directory)
  >lib (directory)
  >libexec (directory)
  >licenses (directory)
  >man (directory)
  >manifest (directory)
  >share (directory)
  >x86_64_w64-mingw32 (directory)
  >mingw64env.cmd
postinstall (directory)
  >pi.bat
  >pi.sh
sbin (directory)
  >awk (directory)
devkitvars.bat
devkitvars.ps1
dk.rb
m.ico
msys.bat
msys.ico
```

I know these files and directories were the ones extracted because I carefully checked that the creation date of these files and directories matched the exact time of extraction.

With my files and directories extracted, I then ran the following commands

```
chdir C:\Ruby200
ruby dk.rb init
ruby dk.rb review
ruby dk.rb install
```

I then ran bundle install and gem install json -v '1.8.1' again and was met with some unusual output.

```
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:130:38: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:130:38: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'convert_UTF8_to_JSON':
generator.c:227:23: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:227:23: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:227:23: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:228:25: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:228:25: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:228:25: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'mHash_to_json':
generator.c:330:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Win
t-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'mArray_to_json':
generator.c:342:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Win
t-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'mFixnum_to_json':
generator.c:352:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Win
t-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'mBignum_to_json':
generator.c:362:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Win
t-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'mFloat_to_json':
generator.c:372:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Win
t-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'mString_to_json':
generator.c:394:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Win
t-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'mTrueClass_to_json':
generator.c:449:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Win
t-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'mFalseClass_to_json':
generator.c:459:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Win
t-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'mNilClass_to_json':
generator.c:469:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Win
t-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_configure':
generator.c:524:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Win
t-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:532:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:532:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:532:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:533:34: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:533:34: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:533:34: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:540:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:540:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:540:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:541:33: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:541:33: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:541:33: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:548:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:548:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:548:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:549:40: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:549:40: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:549:40: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:556:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:556:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:556:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:557:36: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:557:36: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:557:36: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:564:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:564:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:564:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:565:37: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:565:37: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:565:37: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'set_state_ivars':
generator.c:613:21: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:613:21: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:613:21: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:615:24: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:615:24: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:615:24: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_to_h':
generator.c:630:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Win
t-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'generate_json_object':
generator.c:700:20: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:700:20: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:700:20: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'generate_json_array':
generator.c:746:20: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:746:20: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:746:20: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_prepare_buffer':
generator.c:860:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Win
t-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_partial_generate':
generator.c:890:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Win
t-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'isArrayOrObject':
generator.c:902:23: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:902:23: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:902:23: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:903:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:903:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:903:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_generate':
generator.c:920:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Win
t-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_initialize':
generator.c:950:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Win
t-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_init_copy':
generator.c:968:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Win
t-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:969:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Win
t-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_indent':
generator.c:1012:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_indent_set':
generator.c:1024:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1026:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1026:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1026:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1035:32: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1035:32: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1035:32: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_space':
generator.c:1049:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_space_set':
generator.c:1062:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1064:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1064:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1064:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1073:31: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1073:31: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1073:31: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_space_before':
generator.c:1086:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_space_before_set':
generator.c:1098:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1100:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1100:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1100:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1109:38: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1109:38: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1109:38: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_object_nl':
generator.c:1123:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_object_nl_set':
generator.c:1136:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1138:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1138:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1138:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1146:35: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1146:35: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1146:35: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_array_nl':
generator.c:1159:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_array_nl_set':
generator.c:1171:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1173:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1173:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1173:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1181:34: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1181:34: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1181:34: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_check_circular_p':
generator.c:1196:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_max_nesting':
generator.c:1208:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_max_nesting_set':
generator.c:1220:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_allow_nan_p':
generator.c:1233:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_ascii_only_p':
generator.c:1245:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_quirks_mode_p':
generator.c:1256:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_quirks_mode_set':
generator.c:1267:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_depth':
generator.c:1279:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_depth_set':
generator.c:1291:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_buffer_initial_length':
generator.c:1304:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_buffer_initial_length_set':
generator.c:1317:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.
1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/ge
nerator/gem_make.out
```

I have no idea what any of that means, but it looks like I ran into some trouble there. I admit that I am lost and have to ask for help here. Any advice will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I installed Ruby on our Windows 2012 server, I did not extract the devkit directly in the Ruby200 folder.  Have a folder inside the Ruby200 folder labeled "devkit" and extract the devkit zip folder inside there.

Also make sure your PATH contains:

C:\windows\system32;
C:\windows
C:{where you installed Ruby}\bin

You will also need to have node.js I believe if you want to use turbolinks.  You will need to set the path for that as well.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. So, would it be best if I create a new folder inside c:\Ruby200 named 'devkit', delete the devkit files extracted to Ruby200, and then re-extract it to c:\Ruby200\devkit? I gather, that's what you'd like me to do. Also, I apologize but I do not understand what make sure your PATH contains means?

Comment: Yes.  Sorry for getting back to you later.

Comment: Also your PATH variable needs to have C:\row\ruby\bin added to it if it is not already there from installing Ruby.

Comment: What is a PATH variable? And how do I know what it contains and how to change it? Sorry if this seems like a stupid question, but I really don't know.

Comment: Open up a command prompt and type in PATH. It will list everything stored in your PATH variable. If C:\Ruby200\bin is not there, then add it by entering in the command line "set PATH=%PATH%;C:\{wherever you installed Ruby}\bin"

I would just uninstall Ruby and reinstall it. While installing, it should ask if you want to add Ruby to your PATH. Just check that box.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I typed in PATH and got the following array. C:\Ruby200\bin; C:\Windows\system32; C:Windows\System32\Wbem; C:Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\Hewlett-Packard\SimplePass; C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared; C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\nodejs\; C:\Users\********\AppData\Roaming\npm

Comment: It looks like my PATH contains C:\Ruby200\bin and C:\Windows\system32, two things that you said were required. But it seems I also need C:\Windows. Should I add that?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes you will need C:\Windows